# About Binance API

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to learn my open position information (in Futures) with Python but I can't.

How can I find out my position information using the Binance API?

Here is that i try;

```
from binance.client import Client
import MyAPI

Login = Client(MyAPI.KEY, MyAPI.SECRET)

myPosition = Login.futures_position_information(symbol='BTCUSDT')
print(myPosition)
```

and server response;

```
[{'symbol': 'XRPUSD_210625', 'positionAmt': '0', 'entryPrice': '0.00000000', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxQty': '500000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notionalValue': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0'}, {'symbol': 'LTCUSD_210625', 'positionAmt': '0', 'entryPrice': '0.00000000', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxQty': '2500', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notionalValue': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0'}, {'symbol': 'EOSUSD_PERP', 'positionAmt': '0', 'entryPrice': '0.00000000', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxQty': '10000', 'marginType': 'cross', 
'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notionalValue': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0'}, {'symbol': 'LTCUSD_210924', 'positionAmt': '0', 'entryPrice': '0.00000000', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxQty': '2500', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notionalValue': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0'}, {'symbol': 'FILUSD_PERP', 'positionAmt': '0', 'entryPrice': '0.00000000', 
'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxQty': '5000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notionalValue': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0'}, {'symbol': 'ADAUSD_210625', 'positionAmt': '0', 'entryPrice': '0.00000000', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxQty': '500000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'notionalValue': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0'}
```

PS: I have one open position now. It's Long Position.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what's the specific problem with it?

Comment: i try `client.futures_coin_position_information()` but that response is all future coin, not my open position.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: `from binance.client import Client
import MyAPI

Login = Client(MyAPI.KEY, MyAPI.SECRET)

myPosition= Login.futures_coin_position_information()
print(myPosition)`

Comment: [Edit] the question, and include the expected and actual results.

Comment: ok. i am edit my question. Thanks

Comment: try: orders = Login.get_all_orders(symbol='BTCUSDT', limit=10)  do you see yor order?

Comment: @Max, No, I don't try to fech orders, i try to fetch MY OPEN POSITION.